# React/Redux - Passing props from one container to another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, containers, react-redux

I'm fairly new to Redux so if my implementation is wrong, please advice.

In my current app, I have two containers. Essentially the information that I want is: from one of the container, I'd like to pass a prop to the other container.

Specifically, I want **myArray** variable from **Board** to pass it down to the **Controller** container.

Here's what I've done so far:

**containers/board**

```
class Board extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.onClickToggle = this.onClickToggle.bind(this)
  }
  onClickToggle(coord){
    this.props.onCellClick(coord)
  }
  componentDidMount() {

  }
  render(){
    const height = this.props.grid.height
    const width = this.props.grid.width
    let rows = [];
    let myArray = []
    for (let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
      let rowID = `row${y}`;
      let bin = [];
      let obj = {}
      for (let x = 0; x < width; x++){
        let cellID = `${y}-${x}`;
        let index = y * width + x //index of grid;
        let status = this.props.grid.cells[index];//0 = dead, 1 = alive
        bin.push(
          <Cell
            key={x}
            id={cellID}
            status={status}
            onClick={() => this.onClickToggle({x,y})}
          />)
        obj[cellID] = status
      }
      rows.push(<tr key={y} id={rowID}>{bin}</tr>)
      myArray.push(obj);
      <Controller coord={myArray} />
    }
    return(
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col s12 board"></div>
            <table id="simple-board">
               <tbody>
                 {rows}
               </tbody>
             </table>
          </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return bindActionCreators({onCellClick}, dispatch)
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    grid: state.grid
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Board)
```

**containers/controller**

```
class Controller extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.test = this.test.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
  }

  test(){
    // this.props.start
    console.log(this.props)
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col s12 controller">
            <a onClick={this.test} className="waves-effect waves-light btn">Start</a>
            <a onClick={this.props.clear} className="waves-effect waves-light btn">Clear</a>
            <a onClick={this.props.randomize}className="waves-effect waves-light btn">Randomize</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return bindActionCreators({clear,randomize,start}, dispatch)
}


export default connect(null,mapDispatchToProps)(Controller)
```

I understand how to pass props to components, but I haven't faced a situation of passing props from one container to another one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `<Controller coord={myArray} />` from the for loop. You can nest the controller inside return statement like below, to access its values.

**containers/board**

```
return(

  <div className="container">

   <Controller coord={myArray} />

    <div className="row">
      <div className="col s12 board"></div>
        <table id="simple-board">
           <tbody>

           </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
  </div>
)
```

**containers/controller**

```
test(){
  // this.props.start
  console.log(this.props.coord)
}
```